# Creating a pool in Azure with python SDK

Tags: azure, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I'm trying to create a pool based on standard marketplace ubuntu image. I'm using [Azure 4.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure/), [image refernce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-batch/azure.batch.models.imagereference?view=azure-python), [vm config reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-batch/azure.batch.models.VirtualMachineConfiguration?view=azure-python) and other things are written based off learn.microsoft.com

Here's my code:

```
import azure.batch as batch
from azure.batch import BatchServiceClient
from azure.batch.batch_auth import SharedKeyCredentials
from azure.batch import models
import sys

account = 'mybatch'
key = 'Acj1hh7vMR6DSodYgYEghjce7mHmfgfdgodYgYEghjce7mHmfgodYgYEghjce7mHmfgCj/7f3Zs1rHdfgPsdlA=='
batch_url = 'https://mybatch.westeurope.batch.azure.com'

creds = SharedKeyCredentials(account, key)
batch_client = BatchServiceClient(creds, base_url = batch_url)


pool_id = 'mypool3'

if batch_client.pool.exists( pool_id ):
  print( 'pool exists' )
  sys.exit()

vmc = models.VirtualMachineConfiguration(
  image_reference = models.ImageReference(
    offer = 'UbuntuServer', 
    publisher = 'Canonical',
    sku = '16.04.0-LTS', 
    version = 'latest', 
    virtual_machine_image_id = None
  ) ,
  node_agent_sku_id = 'batch.node.ubuntu 16.04'
)

pool_config = models.CloudServiceConfiguration(os_family = '5')

new_pool = models.PoolAddParameter(
  id = pool_id, 
  vm_size = 'small', 
  cloud_service_configuration = pool_config, 
  target_dedicated_nodes = 1,
  virtual_machine_configuration = vmc
)

batch_client.pool.add(new_pool)
```

Here are some image values I took from the azure portal ( Add pool JSON Editor ):

>

> "imageReference": {
>
> "publisher": "Canonical",
>
> "offer": "UbuntuServer",
>
> "sku": "16.04.0-LTS"
>
> },

But when I ran the code I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 80, in <module>
    batch_client.pool.add(new_pool)
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/batch/operations/pool_operations.py", line 310, in add
    raise models.BatchErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.batch.models.batch_error_py3.BatchErrorException: {'additional_properties': {}, 'lang': 'en-US', 'value': 'The value provided for one of the properties in the request body is invalid.\nRequestId:d8a1f7fa-6f40-4e4e-8f41-7958egas6efa\nTime:2018-12-05T16:18:44.5453610Z'}
```

What image values are wrong ? Is this possible to get more information on this error with RequestId ?

---

**UPDATE**

I found a [newer example here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-batch-samples/blob/master/Python/Batch/sample2_pools_and_resourcefiles.py) which is using this helper [select_latest_verified_vm_image_with_node_agent_sku](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-batch-samples/blob/master/Python/Batch/common/helpers.py) to get the image ref. Same error `The value provided for one of the properties in the request body is invalid.`

Comment: You can take a look at this [link](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/batch/batch-linux-nodes.md).

Comment: @CharlesXu This example also gives me errors. And it doesn't say what SDK version it is written for. I tried to update the code to fix errors, but next line also gives me an error and so on. The last one was `AttributeError: 'BatchServiceClientConfiguration' object has no attribute 'signed_session'`. Anyway, the values for creating image reference are the same. Thanks for the link anyway.

Comment: Ok, I also did the test. I will give the answer if I resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a lof of confusing examples on the net, or they simply match older version of SDK.

Digging deeper into the docs I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-batch/azure.batch.models.pooladdparameter?view=azure-python).

> cloud_service_configuration CloudServiceConfiguration The cloud
>   service configuration for the pool. **This property and
>   virtualMachineConfiguration are mutually exclusive** and one of the
>   properties must be specified. This property cannot be specified if the
>   Batch account was created with its poolAllocationMode property set to
>   'UserSubscription'.

In my case I could use only
`cloud_service_configuration = pool_config` **or** `virtual_machine_configuration = vmc`, but not both at the same time.

This is the working code:

```
new_pool = models.PoolAddParameter(
  id = pool_id, 
  vm_size = 'BASIC_A1', 
  target_dedicated_nodes = 1,
  virtual_machine_configuration = vmc
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the test with your code and get the same error. Then I research and change some things in the code. And the problem caused by two things.

**First**:

```
pool_config = models.CloudServiceConfiguration(os_family = '5')
```

You can take a look at the description of the `models.CloudServiceConfiguration`:

```
os_family: The Azure Guest OS family to be installed on the virtual
     machines in the pool. Possible values are: 2 - OS Family 2, equivalent to
     Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1. 3 - OS Family 3, equivalent to Windows Server
     2012. 4 - OS Family 4, equivalent to Windows Server 2012 R2. 5 - OS Family
     5, equivalent to Windows Server 2016. For more information, see Azure
     Guest OS Releases
```

Maybe this property is set for windows. You can take away this configuration.

**Second**:

```
vm_size = 'small',
```

You should set the `vmSize` with a real VM size. For example, **Standard_A1**. See [Choose a VM size for compute nodes in an Azure Batch pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-pool-vm-sizes).

Hope this will help you. If you need more help please give me the message.

Comment: Thank you, but :-) : First - I already tried all numbers, and this parameter is required. Second - I tried values like 'Standard_A1_v2' and they don't work (ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-sizes-specs#a-series ) . 'small' works though. Basically all my code works except for `virtual_machine_configuration` part. If you remove `virtual_machine_configuration = vmc` from my example, it will create a pool of windows VMs.

Comment: Your answer triggered my into finding the solution. Thank you :)